# Javascript Eslint Error: Cannot find module 'optionator'

Tags: javascript, eslint

We've got some error and we try to install optionator but nothing happened. We're using Linux

We're trying to `npm i` from package.json which include this dependencies

```
"optionalDependencies": { 
  "eslint-config-<name>": "github:<username>/<repo>" 
}
```

then we tried to run `npm i optionator` but still get the same error

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'optionator'
    Require stack:
    - /usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/options.js
    - /usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/cli.js
    - /usr/share/nodejs/eslint/bin/eslint.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/options.js:12:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/options.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/bin/eslint.js'
```

Anyone who experienced this, please help us. Thanks

Comment: Could you show what code you are running or the command?

Comment: Have you done an npm init? like you have the node modules and such in the directory?

Comment: We're trying to npm i from package.json which include this package `"optionalDependencies": { "eslint-config-<name>": "github:<username>/<repo>" }` then we tried to run `npm i optionator`. It's still error the same @FivePlyPaper

Comment: we just trying `npm install`..wil do `npm init`..thanks @FivePlyPaper

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to give full access to package-lock.json

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have not done an npm init then that is the issue. `npm init` initializes the project and will add the `node_modules` folder to the working directory, this will set it up as a node project. Then to install a dependency just run a `npm install <dependency>` although I do recommend doing a `--save` afterwards as well as it just ensures that the package is put in your current directory

```
$ npm init
$ npm install optionator --save
```

[npm-init | npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-init)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked until when I initialized the project in a new directory and reinstalled all the dependent modules afresh.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using linux do this

```bash
sudo eslint init
```